# Declaring components in Android crashes program

Tags: android, components, declaration

Im trying to initialize component in android, i searched internet and found this type of declaration, but it makes my program to force close right at startup. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText edit =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3); // This code makes my program come up totally empty and crash in few seconds after being blank.


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not get a reference to any widget before you have set the layout. Try the following instead:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText edit;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edit =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    }

    public void startScan(View view){
        //edit.append(seekBar1.getProgress()+"\n");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```